# Creating a landing page with an extension using shoutem builder

Tags: shoutem

It seems likes I am limited by the shoutem builder to having a default Main Navigation, whereby all of the other screens are wrapped by it. Is it possible for me to create a landing page where my users can sign in, and then segue to the Main Navigation? How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `shoutem.auth` (Users) extension does something you're asking for. [It displays a screen before any shortcuts](https://github.com/shoutem/extensions/blob/master/shoutem.auth/app/middleware.js#L82) (i.e. navigation items) are displayed. It achieves this through the use of a middleware which is implemented throughout the entire Shoutem app, visible in the `@shoutem/core` package.

You could use a similar pattern to achieve your landing/onboarding page extension.